# Connect 5V DC Fan to Ardumoto

Tags: arduino-motor-shield

I wish to connect 2 simple 5V DC Brushless Fan (80x80x15mm, https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9649) to Ardumoto (https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9815).

Therefore, how to I turn on/off the fan as I do not know how to address it? Do I need to connect a power supply to the Ardumoto, to the Arduino board or 2 separate power supplies to each one of them?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the [schematic](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/DevTools/Arduino/Ardumoto_v13.pdf) on the product page it shows that the `Vin` from the arduino is connected to the same Vin on the shield and the Vin to the motor driver. So it is either or where you want to connect power.

With regards to controlling the fan, brushless fans are polarized because of the internal control circuitry, this means that **it cannot be made to reverse**, therefore you should always give the direction pin a high signal. The [Sparkfun hookup guide](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutohttps://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/ardumoto-shield-hookup-guiderials/ardumoto-shield-hookup-guide) has a example code which shows how to control the motor shield, and some explination.